# Method can't get values from SOQL query based on pagereference

Tags: visualforce, soql, class, pagereference, method

I have those two methods inside my RSVP class :

```
 public LIST<News__c> getExcerpts() {
        String paramId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('eventid');
        return [SELECT Title__C, Excerpt__c FROM News__c WHERE id = :paramId LIMIT 1];  
    }
    public PageReference rsvpMe() {
        // QUERY EVENT
        try {
            List<News__c> eventList = [
                select Name,
                    Title__c,
                    Id
                from News__c
                where Id = :paramId
            ];


            // EVENT NOT FOUND
            if (eventList.isEmpty()) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, 'The event was not found.'));
                return null;
            }
```

When I use the command button on my page the following error gets displayed "The event was not found") I cannot find anything wrong with this piece of code and cannot find an error in the methods. Anyone know how to make it work ?

here are the visualforce page code for the form that activates this method:

```
        <form role="form">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Confirm Email Address</label>
                    <apex:inputText styleClass="form-control" id="email" required="true" value="{!email}" />
                </div>
                <apex:inputHidden id="eventid" value="{!eventid}" />
                <script>
                    var jsEmail = "{!$Component.email}";
                    var jsEvent = "{!$Component.eventid}";
                </script>
                <script>
                window.onload=function()
                   {
                document.getElementById(jsEmail).value = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.email}";
                   };
      </script>

  <apex:commandButton action="{!rsvpMe}" value="RSVP" id="rsvpButton" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" />
```

And here is the output that redirects them to the form page page:

```
 <apex:outputLink styleclass="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'News_ReadMoreLatestNews', 'click', 'Read more news');" value="{!$Page.calypso_news}?id={!article.id}">Read More</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Your eventList array is empty. Maybe the paramId variable is null. Check out its content with System.debug(). Also, verify whether your current page contains a parameter named eventid and whether it's valid.

Comment: The current page url is this: calypso_news?id=a0p7E0000005UPhQAM  it doesnt let me get the debug for param id but the SOQL query seems fine to me.  Can you see any errors ?

Comment: The SOQL query is fine. It is just return nothing. Your returned list is empty. I see the param name is id and not eventid, so try this: Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

Comment: <apex:outputLink value="/calypso_RSVP?eventid={!article.id}" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-xs-block" id="register" rendered="{!IF(AND(article.Category__c == 'Events', ISBLANK(article.Custom_Registration_URL__c), article.Event_Date_End__c > NOW()), TRUE, FALSE)}">Register <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></apex:outputLink>

Comment: thats the button for the redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're defining paramid only in the context of the getExcerpts method, in which case it's value won't be accessible to other methods.

You should define it as a public variable outside the method to allow it to be accessed from other methods.

Eg.

Public string paramid { get; set; }

Then set its value in the getExcerpts method as you are already trying to but without "string" at the start.

Ie.

paramid = ApexPages.CurrentPage()  etc...

Also, how are you calling the getExcerpts method - as an Action on the page?  Or from a constructor method?  The paramid variable won't be populated until The getExcerpts method has been run...